# Canvas - xAPI Integration with LTI OAuth Params

Tags: canvas, tin-can-api, lti, xapi

We are using LTI1.3 and xAPI to interact with Canvas.

LTI1.3: https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.lti_dev_key_config.html

For xAPI integration, we are following this documentation: https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.xapi.html

The document says to sign the request with `LTI OAuth Params`. Do we have an example on this?

We are using `OAuth2.0 for LTI1.3`. Including the access token in "Authorization" header of `xAPI` request is not working.

Or does the document means to sign using OAuth1.0 params?

Do we have an example with details of all the parameters to be passed and signature method used? A curl command would be helpful.